# How do I select the DisplayMember or DisplayValue of the currently selected item?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, combobox, datasource

I have a function which populates the drop down list and sets display and value members from a BindingSource, but I don't know how to select only the value of the selected item.

Dictionary bindingsource population:

```
    public Dictionary<int, string> Get_List_of_ManualSchemes()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT [idGMRScheme],[SchemeName] FROM [DBA_Admin].[dbo].[GMR_Schemes]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    comboSource.Add((int)reader["idGMRScheme"], (string)reader["SchemeName"]);
                }
        }
        return comboSource;
    }
```

Populating the combo with it:

```
        public void Populate_ManualSchemes_Combolist(Dictionary<int, string> comboSource)
        {
            cb_SchemesManual.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
            cb_SchemesManual.ValueMember = "value";
            cb_SchemesManual.DisplayMember = "text";
        }
```

I try doing:

```
cb_ManualSchemes.SelectedValue
```

and it returns the displayed text, not the id, and when I try:

```
cb_ManualSchemes.SelectedText
```

it returns nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you using a dictionary which is a collection of key value pairs. Display member and value members must match the properties of an item in the dictionary

Try the following

```
 cb_SchemesManual.ValueMember = "Key";
 cb_SchemesManual.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

Comment: This lets me now bring through the id using .selectedValue, but doing .selectedtext is still null, however if I do .selectedItem it displays the id and the text as '[2, SchemeName]'

Comment: I'm a numpty, I can just used combobox.Text to get the text -.-' thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Bund your combobo using the below code so that u can access the value using `cb_ManualSchemes.SelectedValue`

```
  public void Populate_ManualSchemes_Combolist(Dictionary<int, string> comboSource)
    {
      cb_SchemesManual.DataSource=comboSource;
       cb_SchemesManual.ValueMember = "Key";
       cb_SchemesManual.DisplayMember = "Value";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a DataTable for comboSource instead of Dictionary.

```
public DataTable Get_List_of_ManualSchemes()
    {
        DataTable comboSource = new DataTable();
        comboSource.Columns.Add("value", typeof(Int32));
        comboSource.Columns.Add("text");
        DataRow newRow;

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT [idGMRScheme],[SchemeName] FROM [DBA_Admin].[dbo].[GMR_Schemes]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    newRow = comboSource.NewRow();
                    newRow["value"] = (Int32)reader["idGMRScheme"];
                    newRow["text"] = reader["SchemeName"].ToString();
                    comboSource.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
        }
        return comboSource;
    }

    public void Populate_ManualSchemes_Combolist(DataTable comboSource)
    {
        cb_SchemesManual.DataSource = comboSource;
        cb_SchemesManual.ValueMember = "value";
        cb_SchemesManual.DisplayMember = "text";

    }
```